# Login con google en genexus

Tags: genexus

Quiero crear un login con google en un web panel en genexus, pero en la wiki no encuentro una sintaxis. Alguien sabria cual es la sintaxis ?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Genexus y qué generador estás utilizando? ¿Qué has probado hasta el momento? Por favor agrega esta información y el código que has probado a tu pregunta. Para realizar un login con Google deberías utilizar GAM y seguir la siguiente documentación: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?29013,GAM+-+Google+Authentication+Type

Comment: EL genexus 18 v5 estoy utilizando. Ya me registre en google y active el gam. Pero no encuentro la forma de como llegar a la parte donde pedir los datos al cliente. Al menos en la wiki para web no muestran la sintaxis, solo para smart

Comment: En el caso de web, tienes que ver el objeto GAMExampleLogin para detalles de cómo se ejecuta el login, segun la documentación si activas la autenticación por Google ya debería aparecerte en ese mismo objeto: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?39427,GAMExampleLogin+object

Comment: Entiendo. gracias